# wordpress: remove year and month in url using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to Remove year and month in url

https://www.newkannada.com/2016/10/mukunda-murari-kannada-songs-download.html
To
https://www.newkannada.com/mukunda-murari-kannada-songs-download.html

this is my code

## BEGIN WordPress

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

## END WordPress

Answer (score 0):

To change URL format, you need go to dashboard and go to `Settings` -> `Permalinks`. And in **Common Settings** section, select **Custom structure**. Next, input `/%postname%.html` into this field.

Comment: i had tried this, still https://www.newkannada.com/2016/10/mukunda-murari-kannada-songs-download.html showing 404 error